# How to loop through a list of Mono objects in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I am new to Kotlin, sorry if it is simple but couldn't find the answer on the internet. I have a list of Mono objects. The objects have user information including email, like

```
data class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var email: String){...}
```

And a Mono which has a list of User objects:

```
Mono<List<User>>
```

Which is returned from Web client. I want to loop through this list and filter the list based on a given email. How can I do that in Kotlin?

Comment: I don't know what a Mono is, but if you can access the list you can filter it with ``theList.filter { it.email == requiredEmail }`` which returns a new list with only the matching items

Comment: Is this the Mono you're talking about? - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.1/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

Comment: Do you really have a list of Monos, or do you have a single Mono whose result is a List of Users?

Comment: If you're using coroutines, you can include [kotlinx-coroutines-reactive](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive) in your project, and get the result of the Mono using the Mono.awaitSingle() extension function.

Comment: @cactustictacs It doesn't give me an iterator inside the filter. Like in your example, 'it' inside the iterator is still considered a list, and not a pointer to an element in the list.

Comment: @Trevor Yes it is.

Comment: ``filter`` is a function on an ``Iterable``, running it on a ``List<T>`` passes each ``T`` into the filter function you provide (called `it` by default). Are you sure you're not running ``filter`` on the ``Mono`` itself, which would pass in ``List<User>``s to the function? If you don't already have your list, just the thing that produces lists, maybe you want to do something like `myMono.map { list -> list.filter { it.email == requiredEmail } }` to transfer each emitted list into a filtered list? (Again I've never used this, just going by conventions here!)